# VertexShapeFunction with string pattern matching

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching

I am trying to visualize a heterogeneous graph which nodes are categorical. Here is a dummy graph for implementation:

Input is

```
graph = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{"u0", "c1"}, {"u1", "c3"}, {"u2", "c0"}, {"u3", 
   "c2"}, {"u4", "c1"}, {"u0", "i0"}, {"u1", "i0"}, {"u2", 
   "i0"}, {"u3", "i1"}, {"u4", "i2"}}
```

And it looks like this by specifying vertex coordinates.

[image]

I would like to customize vertex shape by using `VertexShapeFunction`,   but I cannot make the pattern matching work, for instance, I would like to make the nodes starts with `m` have shape square:

```
Graph[graph, VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexShapeFunction -> {_?StringStartsQ["u"] -> "Square" }]
```

I am aware the it should be a pattern, as

```
CompleteGraph[5, VertexShapeFunction -> {_?EvenQ -> "Star"}, VertexSize -> 0.2]
```

but I don't know how to make pattern work, I tried:

```
Cases[{"u1", "p1"}, _?StringStartsQ[#, "u"] &]
```

Returns empty list.

I know `StringCases` and `Select` can easily returns the strings I want, but unfortunately, seems only `Cases` with pattern matching would work for VertexShapeFunction

The following two works but it's not pattern matching.

```
StringCases[{"u1", "p1"}, "u" ~~ _]
Select[{"u1", "p1"}, StringStartsQ[#, "u"] &]
```

Comment: you define `graph` but then reference `eMC`.  None of the vertices in `graph` start with `m`.

Comment: It seems counterintuitive, but you have to use `VertexShapeFunction -> {_?(StringStartsQ["m"]) -> "Square" }]`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Jason, I just fixed the inconsistency.

Comment: but `VertexShapeFunction -> {_?(StringStartsQ["u"]) -> "Square" }]` doesn't work at all.

Comment: [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/QkRa3AFQ) doesn't work for you?  What version are you using?

Comment: It works! Though I don't understand why the extra `()` is so magical!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122839/discussion-between-wenzhen-and-jason-b).

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, thank you guys so much! It's been almost 10 years of using Mathematica but still so much new things to learn everyday!